# How can I revert a migrations from the control panel?

Tags: craft3, plugin-development

Is it possible to revert a migrations from the control panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can usually ignore the safeDown() method, as Craft doesn’t have a way to revert migrations from the control panel.

For more information you can refer this documentation
https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/migrations.html#creating-migrations

Thanks.